# Downloading data from the page PHP

Tags: php

I wanted to download the table of season Kent Bazemore from website:
http://www.nba.com/players/kent/bazemore/203145

Who knows how to do it?
I have already this:

`$content = file_get_contents("http://www.nba.com/players/kent/bazemore/203145"); 
preg_match(..., $content, $result);
echo($result);`

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP dom document to solve your problem.
i suggest you library to do this
its very easy 
go through this link
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/